# Is there a term for two or more words within a word?

Tags: terminology

As the title says, I was wondering if there was a term for two or more words within a word, for example:

'*Beyond*' is '*yo*' enclosed in '*bend*'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe here's what you might be looking for,

> ## *"Kangaroo word"* or *"marsupial"*
>
> This refers to a word carrying another word within it (without
> transposing any letters). Example: *encourage* contains *courage, cog,
> cur, urge, core, cure, nag, rag, age, nor, rage and enrage.*

([5. Kangaroo word or marsupial](https://theweek.com/articles/464433/palindromes-anagrams-9-other-names-alphabetical-antics))

Comment: I think it's the closest that I'll get, thank you!